# ResultSetMapping addScalarResult associative array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-native-query

In my project with Symfony2, I'm using Doctrine createNativeQuery, and I would like to get an associative array.

This is my code

```php
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'name');
$rsm->addScalarResult('phone_one', 'phoneOne');
$rsm->addScalarResult('phone_two', 'phoneTwo');
```

I have this result:

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "id" => "975"
        "name" => "one name"
        "phoneOne" => "122345556"
        "phoneTwo" => "345566789"
    ]
  1 => array:4 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "id" => "976"
        "name" => "two name"
        "phoneOne" => "122345556"
        "phoneTwo" => "345566789"
    ]
]
```

It's posible this result?

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "id" => "975"
        "name" => "one name"
        "phones" => [
            "phoneOne" => "122345556"
            "phoneTwo" => "345566789"
        ]
    ]
  1 => array:4 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "id" => "976"
        "name" => "two name"
        "phones" => [
            "phoneOne" => "122345556"
            "phoneTwo" => "345566789"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you needing a native query with this simple set? I'm really curious.

Comment: I would like to solve all in one query. :)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the result you want, why not create a OneToMany for Users to Phones? I would highly suggest you do that.